# Angular 4, multiple api calls and wait for results

Tags: angular, angular-promise

I'm calling service api in loop and then I want to wait for the all results. I'm not sure how can I use Observable.forkJoin here.

Component:

```
for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++{
    this.component.getData(data[i].id).then((result: any) => {


                })
    }
```

Service:

```
getData(parameters:any): Promise<Object> {
    return this.query(parameters)
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively calling an asynchronous API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813893/recursively-calling-an-asynchronous-api-call)

Comment: @Knostradamus I don't think there's anything recursive about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), which waits for all promises to resolve before executing your callback.

```
let promises = data.map(d => this.component.getData(d.id));

Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: We don't need for loop here? for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++{ let promises = data.map(d => this.component.getData(d.id));}

Comment: Ah, you must not be familiar with [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).  It's functionally equivalent to your original for loop except that it also builds a new array from the values returned from the lambda function passed-into it.  In this case, the lambda function passed to `map` returns a promise, so `map` returns an array of promises.